# Where is libpcap.dylib?

Tags: macos, libpcap, macos-big-sur

I able to load libpcap.dylib which is confusing cause I can't figure out the actual file location. Doing find / -name libpcap.A.dylib or libpcap.dylib says no such file.

Also finder search with libpcap just results in libpcap.A.tbd and libpcap.rb.

libpcap.A.tbd shows "Install location /usr/lib/libpcap.A.dylib", but it does not actually exist there.

I wanted to locate the actual dylib file cause I running into issue with being able to import function,  So I wanted to check file to make sure I have function names correct.

Answer (score 1):

> So I wanted to check file to make sure I have function names correct.

The first thing to check is the pcap man page - from the command line, it'd be

```
man pcap
```

It's a bit long, but it should mention all the functions available in libpcap; it may be easier than

```
nm /usr/lib/libpcap.dylib | egrep ' T '
```

(and doesn't require you to remember that the leading underscores in the output of that command are *NOT* part of the name of the function, they're a leftover from ancient UNIX history).

> Where is libpcap.dylib?

/usr/lib/libpcap.A.dylib.  /usr/lib/libpcap.dylib is a symbolic link to it.

Comment: In macOS Big Sur, `libcap.dylib` is no longer located in `/usr/lib`

Answer (score 1):

Apple has moved the libraries into the DYLD shared cache, so you will no longer find them physically on the filesystem as such.